# Fixing broken naming after merging a groupby pivot_table dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a problem with naming of columns of  dataframe resulting from merging it with its iteration created by group_by.

Generally, the code that creates the mess looks like this:

```
volume_aggrao = volume.groupby(by = ['room_name', 'material', 'RAO']).sum()['quantity']
volume_aggrao_concat = pd.pivot_table(pd.DataFrame(volume_aggrao), index=['room_name', 'material'], columns = ['RAO'], values = ['quantity'])
volume = volume.merge(volume_aggrao_concat, how = 'left', on = ['room_name', 'material'])
```

Now to what it does: the goal of pivot_table is to show 'quantity' variable sum over each category of 'RAO' and it looks like that:

[image: 'volume_aggrao_concat']

And it is fine until you access how it looks on the inside:

```
"(&#39;room_name&#39;, &#39;&#39;)","(&#39;material&#39;, &#39;&#39;)","(&#39;quantity&#39;, &#39;moi&#39;)","(&#39;quantity&#39;, &#39;nao&#39;)","(&#39;quantity&#39;, &#39;onrao&#39;)","(&#39;quantity&#39;, &#39;prom&#39;)","(&#39;quantity&#39;, &#39;sao&#39;)"
1,aluminum,NaN,13.0,NaN,NaN,NaN
1,concrete,151.0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1,plastic,56.0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
1,steel_mark_1,NaN,30.0,2.0,NaN,1.0
1,steel_mark_2,52.0,NaN,88.0,NaN,NaN
2,aluminum,123.0,NaN,84.0,NaN,NaN
2,concrete,155.0,NaN,NaN,30.0,NaN
2,plastic,170.0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
2,steel_mark_1,107.0,NaN,105.0,47.0,NaN
2,steel_mark_2,81.0,41.0,NaN,NaN,NaN
3,aluminum,NaN,NaN,90.0,NaN,79.0
3,concrete,NaN,82.0,NaN,NaN,NaN
3,plastic,1.0,NaN,25.0,NaN,NaN
3,steel_mark_1,116.0,10.0,NaN,136.0,NaN
3,steel_mark_2,NaN,92.0,34.0,NaN,NaN
4,aluminum,50.0,74.0,NaN,NaN,88.0
4,concrete,96.0,NaN,27.0,NaN,NaN
4,plastic,63.0,135.0,NaN,NaN,NaN
4,steel_mark_1,97.0,NaN,28.0,87.0,NaN
4,steel_mark_2,57.0,22.0,7.0,NaN,NaN
```

Nevertheless, I was still able to merge it, with resulting columns being named automatically like that:

[image]

I cannot seem to be able to call these '(quantity, smth)' columns and hence could not even rename them directly. And there i decided to fully reset column namings with `volume.columns = ["id", "room_name", "material", "alpha_UA", "beta_UA", "alpha_F", "beta_F", "gamma_EP", "quantity", "files_id", "all_UA", "RAO", "moi", "nao", "onrao", "prom", "sao"]`, which is indeed bulky, but it worked. Except it did not when one or more of categorical values of "RAO" is missing. For example, there is no "nao" in "RAO" and hence there is no such column created and hence the code has nothing to rename.

I tried fixing it with `volume.rename(lambda x: x.lstrip("(\'quantity\',").strip("\'() \'") if "(" in x else x, axis=1)`, but it seems to do nothing with them.

I want to know if there is a way to rename these columns.

### Data

Here's some example data of 'volume' dataframe you may use to replicate the process with desired output embedded in it to compare

```
"id","room_name","RAO","moi","nao","onrao","prom","sao"
"1","3","onrao","1","","25","",""
"2","4","nao","57","22","7","",""
"4","2","moi","170","","","",""
"6","4","moi","97","","28","87",""
"7","4","moi","97","","28","87",""
"11","1","nao","","13","","",""
"12","4","onrao","97","","28","87",""
"13","2","moi","107","","105","47",""
"18","2","moi","123","","84","",""
"19","2","moi","155","","","30",""
"22","2","moi","170","","","",""
"23","4","sao","50","74","","","88"
"24","4","nao","50","74","","","88"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a cup of coffee and a cold shower, I was able to investigate a bit further and found out that the strange namings are actually tuples and not strings! Knowing that I decided to iterate over columns to change them to strings and then use the filter. A bit bulky once again, but here is a solution:

```
for name in volume.columns:
        names.append(str(name).lstrip("(\'quantity\',").strip("\'() \'"))
```